# Windows Assembly Doubt - x86

Tags: assembly, windows-xp, masm32

I'm building a Windows Assembly program without any macro. So I downloaded a program that was using macros, and I'm converting this into "pure" assembly code.

However I'm facing one issue here. There's a label `@@:` that I don't understand, and also a jump `jne @F` that I didn't get it. What are these 2 symbols?

```
MyWndProc:

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    cmp DWORD PTR [ebp+12], 2 ;WM_DESTROY=2
    jne @F
      push ecx
      push NULL
      mov dword ptr ecx, 7e42ca5ah ;address of PostQuitMessage
      call ecx
      pop ecx
    @@:

    push DWORD PTR [ebp+20]
    push DWORD PTR [ebp+16]
    push DWORD PTR [ebp+12]
    push DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
    call DefWindowProc
    ;mov dword ptr edx, 7e42c17eh
    ;call edx

    leave
    ret 16
```

Also for `PostQuitMessage` API I could hard-code the memory address (on WinXP 32bits SP3 english), but for `DefWindowProc` it compiles, but it breaks when executing. Does someone know why?

Thanks for support guys.

PS.: I'm using masm32

Comment: why "without any macro"?

Comment: Why? Two reasons: 1) I want to see the details of Windows binaries. 2) I want to build an assembly program inside a C program. Why? I'm just a *very* curious guy...

Comment: Hard-coding addresses = no-no.

Comment: @Jens Björnhager: I know this is not a good practice, but as I explained above, this is more a matter of curiosity. I want to have this code free of linker stuffs (at least I need to be sure this is possible). I think this is possible, because I hardcoded address of several API in the code, only for `DefWindowProc` it's not working... dunno why :(

Comment: You can code linker free by actually using an assembler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@@` is an anonymous local label. You could have many of them in the file  The `jne @F` means jump to the nearest `@@` ahead of the current location.

Comment: Couldn't tell you without more code.  Is DefWindowProc another one of your routines?

Comment: No, `DefWindowProc` it's a Windows API. This routine is responsible to get the windows messages... I've found it address on my machine using arwin tool, but this is the only API that I can't hardcode.. but I don't know why I can't do the same I did with `PostQuitMessage`...

Comment: Then you need to make a global symbol declaration for it, and then use the linker to make sure everything gets matched up.  I'm not sure you can depend on it always having the same address.  I am not a windows API expert, though.